# Trigger On Campaign Member Status

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a method that is called from my Campaign Member Trigger Handler.  If a Campaign member's status changes to "Opened" then  Email Opened__c field on the contact object should be incremented by one.  It is working in the UI. But I can not get my test classes to pass. It seems that no matter how I try to change the Campaign Member Status in the test my System.debug  messages read as "Status = Sent." Any help would be much appreciated.

The way I have read the documentation suggestions I should update the member status with the text value not the campaign member status Id. It does work in the UI.

Here are the methods.

```
public with sharing class CampaignMemberUtils {

public static void   main(List<CampaignMember> newList, Map<Id, CampaignMember> oldList){
    //if the contact status has changed and is opened or clicked call score method

    Set<Id> contactIds  = new Set<Id>();

    for (CampaignMember c : newList){
        CampaignMember oldMember = oldList.get(c.Id);
        System.debug('Email status is :' + c.Status);
        if (c.Status == 'Opened' && oldMember.Status != 'Opened'){
            contactIds.add(c.ContactId);
        }
    }
    System.debug('contactsToProcess.Size() = ' + contactIds.size());
        List<Contact> contacts = getContacts(contactIds);
        updateContactOpenScores(contacts);

}
public static void updateContactOpenScores(List<Contact> contacts){
        System.debug('Number of contacts passed to update open score method = ' + contacts.size());
        List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
        for(Contact c : contacts){
            c.Pardot_Emails_Opened__c  +=1;
            contactsToUpdate.add(c);
        }
        update contactsToUpdate;
    }
public static List<Contact> getContacts(Set<Id> ids) {
    List<Contact> contacts = [
            SELECT Id, Pardot_Emails_Opened__c, Pardot_Links_Clicked__c
            FROM Contact
            WHERE Id = :ids
    ];
    return contacts;
}
```

}

Here is the test

```
@IsTest public static void singleRecordFound(){
    Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Acc');
    insert a;
    Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Test Contact', AccountId = a.Id, Pardot_Emails_Opened__c = 0);
    insert c;
    Campaign campaign = new Campaign(Name = 'Test Campaign', IsActive = true);
    insert campaign;
    CampaignMemberStatus  status = new CampaignMemberStatus(CampaignId = campaign.Id, Label = 'Opened');
    insert status;
    CampaignMember campaignMember = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = campaign.Id, ContactId = c.Id);
    insert campaignMember;
    CampaignMember updatedCampaignMember = [SELECT Id, Status FROM CampaignMember LIMIT 1];
    updatedCampaignMember.Status = 'Opened';
    update campaignMember;
    Contact updatedContact = [SELECT Id, Pardot_Emails_Opened__c FROM Contact LIMIT 1];

    System.assertEquals(1, updatedContact.Pardot_Emails_Opened__c);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating the `campaignMember` record and not the one which you change the status of which is `updatedCampaignMember`.

Try:

```
@IsTest public static void singleRecordFound(){
    Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Acc');
    insert a;
    Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Test Contact', AccountId = a.Id, Pardot_Emails_Opened__c = 0);
    insert c;
    Campaign campaign = new Campaign(Name = 'Test Campaign', IsActive = true);
    insert campaign;
    CampaignMemberStatus  status = new CampaignMemberStatus(CampaignId = campaign.Id, Label = 'Opened');
    insert status;
    CampaignMember campaignMember = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = campaign.Id, ContactId = c.Id);
    insert campaignMember;
    CampaignMember updatedCampaignMember = [SELECT Id, Status FROM CampaignMember LIMIT 1];
    updatedCampaignMember.Status = 'Opened';
    update updatedCampaignMember;
    Contact updatedContact = [SELECT Id, Pardot_Emails_Opened__c FROM Contact LIMIT 1];

    System.assertEquals(1, updatedContact.Pardot_Emails_Opened__c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zach, been staring at the screen too long. I can't believe I missed that.